# How to find Minimum run time environment / package to install dependencies

Tags: c#, c++, windows, deployment, setup-deployment

I am making a plugin for outlook using visual studio. I have to deploy it on user's machine and thats why I am finding out minimum run time environment to run my plug in.

Using dependency walker I have found that apart from visual studio tools for office run time, my plug in is dependent on following dlls :---

```
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-ole32-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-shell32-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
```

Now I can see that all api-ms-win-crt-*.dll are part of visual studio 2015 run time environment. So, in my msi file I can set the provision to check the installation using registry setting and provide the msdn link to download it in client machine from Microsoft site.

But I am unable to find that all api-ms-win-downlevel-*.dll are part of which run time package ? It seems in first look, they are part of full windows 7 sdk (as per my search on internet), which is very big to install on client machine (more than 1.5 GB).

Now is there any other way to find out run time package like Visual studio 2015 run time for these downlevel dlls ?

If yes, can we check the installation status, looking in to registry files ?

Thanks

Comment: You are building your code with Visual Studio, so step one should be to get your installer to install the appropriate version of the Visual Studio runtime redistributables (they are required to be installed on machines wanting to run programs compiled by VS). See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: HI Jesper, Thanks for response. I did it already and installed visual studio 2015 run time environment (as I am using VS 2015). But as I have mentioned, these api-ms-win-downlevel*.dll are not part of VS run time environment. I have tested it with vs 2008, vs2010, Microsoft 4.5.1 sdk and Microsoft silverlight SDK as well. But there dlls are not the part of any one.

Comment: You should *not* use Dependency Walker anymore, it has not been maintained for a very long time.  It does not know anything about this MinWin forwarders, they belong to the operating system.  Do not deploy them.

Comment: Hi Hans, No they dont belong to Operating system. I have tested on fresh machine with windows 7 and ms office 2013 (which is my environment ) and these dlls are not present. I have also tested it that if I put these dlls on fresh machine and then run my application, it run fine. So Dependency walker is also working fine.

Comment: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> Multi-threated (/MT). It will link all your standard runtime library into your your plugin.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will try this and will update the result.

Comment: Statically linking the CRT necessitates, that you can no longer pass CRT resources across your plugin boundary. For every problem there's a solution, that's easy, elegant. And wrong.